# Open SSL Decryption issues

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

I'm encrypting files with a script using the following command:

`openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k mysecretpass -in 'source.jpg' -out 'source.enc'`

So far, I've attempted to decrypt 15 different ways, but can't figure it out.
I get all sorts of errors.... and I've followed every other online tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the command you're looking for is

```
 openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -k mysecretpass -in source.enc -out pr0n.jpg
```

enc with the -d flag decrypts.

This would be better suited for [the Security SE site.](http://security.stackexchange.com)